# Suggest some resources/tutorials

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a social networking site using ruby on rails with rails3.

I want to create a friendship model where a user can send request to other users for friendship.Also i want to create group model where a user can create a group and send join group request to other users.

I am currently reading railscasts-episodes / episode-163 for friendship.but i want more resources to refer...pls suggest me some useful resources for the topics i have mentioned above

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NJF,first, be careful of the older references. Rails changed a lot with v3.0, 3.1, and even earlier.

If you're completely new to Rails, I liked St. Laurent's Learning Rails. Although I don't think its been updated for Rails 3.

The standard is Agile Web Development for Rails. The e-book 4th edition is completely up-to-date. http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails